# adding multiple buttons dynamically and add each a click handler in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm trying to add buttons dynamically with Jquery, now for each button, I want to perform a different action, how can I achieve it? Each couple of buttons will toggle after the action is performed
e.g.

- show 1 after click becomes hide1
- show 2 after click becomes hide2
- show 3 after click becomes hide3

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzbhmsjw/) to display what I achieved so far.

```
var randomMeetings = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;


for(var i = 0; i < randomMeetings; i++){
    var expandClient = '<button type="button" class="hide_client" id="_hide_'+ i +'"><i     class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></button><button type="button" class="show_client" id="_show_'+ i +'"><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i></button>'

    $('#myButtons').append(expandClient);

}

for (var i = 0; i < randomMeetings; i++){

    $('#_show_'+i).click(function() {
        $('#_hide_'+i).toggle();       
    });
    $('#_hide_'+i).click(function() {
        $('#_show_'+i).toggle();

    });
}
```

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/vzbhmsjw/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line inside a for loop is not valid:

```
$('#_hide_'+i).toggle();
```

This happens because when the for loop ends and in future a click event happens the value of the variable i is always the last.

You may change your line in (or use a closure like [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) or [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or add an element attribute):

```
$('#' + this.id.replace('hide', 'show')).toggle();
```

So that whenever you click on "_hide_0" you will toggle "_show_0" and so on.

The snippet ([updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzbhmsjw/2/)):

```js
var randomMeetings = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;


for(var i = 0; i < randomMeetings; i++){
    var expandClient = '<button type="button" class="hide_client" id="_hide_'+ i +
            '"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>' + i + '</button>' +
            '<button type="button" class="show_client" id="_show_'+ i
            +'"><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i>' + i + '</button>'

    $('#myButtons').append(expandClient);

    $('#_show_'+i).click(function() {
        var eleId = this.id.replace('show', 'hide');
        console.log("show " + eleId)
        $('#' + eleId).toggle();
    });
    $('#_hide_'+i).click(function() {
        var eleId = this.id.replace('hide', 'show');
        console.log("hide " + eleId)
        $('#' + eleId).toggle();

    });
}
```

```css
.hide_client,.show_client{
    padding:3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="myButtons">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's almost what I am looking for, after fiddling around I still couldn't get to hide the button once clicked (e.g. if I click a button, it will disappear only displaying the second button, and once clicking on this button it will disappear and show the first one). The only solution that comes to my mind is to use $('#_hide_'+i).show(); and $('#_hide_'+i).hide(); but as you mentioned it will not work in the for loop. Any other solution?

Comment: just found out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I edited Gaetano's answer with a single line to hide and display the button once clicked I updated the JS fiddle:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzbhmsjw/3/)

```
$(this).css('display', 'none');
```